# Creating mask effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, mask

I'm have a very simple game i'm built, and the game have the main center game screen ViewController.
And a top view that shows How is the next opponent you need to pass.

[image]

As you see, the white area is the game area, and the blue top view, you can see how is the next opponent.

What i'm trying to do is when you pass a opponent, the last one will animate downwards, but not on the white area, behind it.
I'm trying to create this effect by code, and here it is:

```
-(void)animationPlayerDawnwaords{

    self.backgroundColor = COLOR_BLUE;

    [_playerView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y)];
    [_playerView setHidden:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

        [_playerView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y * 4.0 )];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //
    }];
}
```

But the result is:

[image]

[image]

And i would like to do somthing like this:

[image]

I know the last image is not from the same project, but if it was i would not of asked this lol (;

Any way of achieving this will be much appreciated, Thanks

**Edit**

The white area it the main ViewController and the blue area is a subview of it, i mean, it is on top.
So the option of making the white area the most top view, is not possible.
Hope i managed to explain my self clearly.. thanks

Comment: Try [self.view sendSubviewToBack: _playerView]; before animation

Comment: Thanks for the response, this option is't good for my because the white area is the main VC where everything else is on top of it..

Comment: Add `_playerView` to subView of blue area. And set `blueView.clipsToBounds = YES` and then `animationPlayerDawnwaords`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

**First:**
One liner

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.yourWhiteView];
// this line of code will place your white view on top of everything else
```

**Second:**
if you want more control

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

int whiteViewZ = self.yourWhiteView.layer.zPosition;

// set your playerview z position to be behind your white view
self.playerView.layer.zPosition = whiteViewZ - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the gameView is on top of the _playerView. You can order de hierarchy in storyboard by making sure the gameView is beneath the _playerView (sorry if it's not clear, I made screenshots but I need 10 reputations to post images...) or by code using Akhilrajtr's answer.

Comment: If you make _playerView a subView of the blueView, than _playerView will not be visible when moving outside of blueView's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

If _playerView is a subview of the blue topView, you can set `topView.clipsToBounds = YES;`